Wrapping openapi-generator inside of a node-cli?
I'm struggeling with a conceptual problem.
I'm building tooling on top of OpenAPI. For this, I'd like to create a CLI that wrapps openapi-generator.
This is an application written in Java that I want to extend with some cutom preprocessing and fetching.
OpenApi Generator has a NPM library openapi-generator but all it does is to download the latest version and try to execute this inside of the Java runtime. So not much help.
There are also JAR files but I'm not sure if those would be helpful in this case.
In my CLI I don't want to assume that a user has the java runtime installed. It should "just work" (as long as node is installed).
I'm not the most experienced when it comes to designing CLIs or wrapping Java code but it seems I'm out of luck?
I'm out of ideas and am not sure if this is possible.


You could Dockerise the Java program (and runtime)... but that still has a pre-requisite of Docker for you user
You could convert the Java into Kotlin and create a native binary; but that would be an infeasibly large project to re-write openapi-generator
Graalvm, offers to convert a Jar file (or other variations) into native binary, see Build a Native Executable from a JAR File

